# System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException

Tags: c#, powershell, vmware, pssnapin

I have a problem running a PowerShell Script from my C# Code. The script contains functions from the PowerShell Snapin `VMWare.View.Broker`. I do that in the following way:

```
PSSnapInException psEx;
RunspaceConfiguration runConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
runConfig.AddPSSnapIn("VMWare.View.Broker", out psEx);
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runConfig))
{
    runspace.Open();
    using (Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
    {
        string scriptContent = ReadScriptFromFile(scriptPath);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(scriptContent))
        {
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptContent);
            var results = pipeline.Invoke();
            runspace.Close();
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
                if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.ToString()))
                    scriptResult += result+"_";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my programm with the platform target x64 it works fine. But when I try to execute my programm with x86 I'm getting the following Exception (I need to run the programm with x86 due to other dependencies):

```
System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException: The Windows PowerShell snap-in
 'VMWare.View.Broker' is not installed on this machine.

 at System.Management.Automation.PSSnapInReader.ReadOne(RegistryKey mshSnapInRoot, String mshsnapinId)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Vmware snapin is 64 bit and not 32 bits. The answer is in the error message. You can try to find a 32 bits Vmware snapin and install it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Is it possible to have multiple snapIns installed? For Example One programm works with the x64 Snapin and the other one with the x86

Comment: On theorical point of view it's possible, but do you found the 32 bits Snapin ?